# Why does azure dev show 'Sign in required' error

Tags: azure-devops

I use https://dev.azure.com/ as collaboration tool. When I tries to mention a person in some ticker or pull request it doesn't suggest me any users, so I can't mention them.
[image]

I tried to go through [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsoservice/?p=10493) and [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/128709/sign-in-required.html) guides. They didn't help me.

Any suggestion how to workaround it?

Comment: what if you click more details? :)

Comment: @4c74356b41, you will see this guide (it doesn't work): https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsoservice/?p=10493

Comment: probably worth opening a support ticket in that case

Comment: @4c74356b41, a ticket should exist according to that thread. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/128709/sign-in-required.html I'm not sure those steps solve the problem

Comment: @KostyaVyrodov Do you have permission to read the AAD user?